# Windows - Prevent folder from being moved, renamed or deleted

Tags: windows-8.1, file-permissions

In Windows 8.1, is it possible to set the permissions of the folder to prevent users from renaming, moving or deleting a folder but allowing changes to any of it's contents and if so how?

Comment: Right-click on folder/properties/security. that's all permissions u can assign . or u can set group policy but will affect all folders ( i guess) for that user

Answer (score 3):

Sure. From Windows Explorer, right-click the folder entry and choose Properties > Security > Advanced > Edit > Edit, and give your users permissions to create files/folders, add data, etc., but not to delete or write attributes, etc. You probably won't want to make those permissions inheritable, i.e., choose Apply to This Folder Only.

Answer (score 2):

Normally not. With just setting permissions, you will forward those permissions to the files in the folder. If there are no files in it, but there are folders, then you can just use permissions. But I suppose this will sort of contradict the `any of its content` part.

But there's a method that you can use (that can be defeated though) that'll make you protect a folder in this manner, yet allow any files or folders inside it to do whatever the user pleases with it.

Place an executable in it that you can start and preferably does not use lots of resources, but also will stay open until closed. Turn this into a system service (so the interface part is not shown) using `sc create MyService binPath=c:\path\program.exe start=boot`

Alternatively, you can use any proram that opens a file and keep that file open. The idea is that windows creates a lock to any object inside the folder, and as long as this lock is in place, the folder the object is in cannot be moved, renamed or deleted.